# Console log is not working with Netbeans (Android emulator and Cordova)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, logging, netbeans

Everything works fine except there is no output when calling `console.log(...)` in the Browser window log (Netbeans).

I created a new HTML5 (Cordova Application) project in Netbeans.

I start the android emulator (Intel Atom x86 API Level 19. Galaxy Nexus. With `Use Host GPU` option checked). Then build/run the project `BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 10 seconds)` and I can see the app running in the emulator with the 'Device is ready' text blinking.

But there is not console log output. I have made sure the Debugger Console plugin is selected (inside the project properties). I also have added `android:debuggable="true"` inside `<application .../>` tag in AndroidManifest.xml file. And still no console log output.

I have also tested with API 21 and still no ouput from `console.log`

What am I missing?

I'm using cordova 4.3.0, Netbeans 8.0.2, Java version: 1.8.0_45, Apache Ant 1.9.4.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** I can see the log entry with DDMS but since I'm using `Use Host GPU`, Logcat is spammed with an error and by the looks of it, the filter doesn't work as expected and sometimes it stops logging for whatever reason (DDMS). At least I know the `console.log` call works inside the javascript. By the looks of it, DDMS is buggy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found out why Netbeans isn't picking up any log output.

Debugger console seems to only work for Xcode and/or maybe Netbeans isn't configured to get any log from LogCat. Cordova redirects `console.log` calls to their respective platform logger. That's why I can see the log entry just fine with `adb logcat -s "CordovaLog"` (CordovaLog being the tag to filer).

**Edit:**
Netbeans doesn't connect fast enough and it doesn't show you earlier logs. I recommend to use Chrome remote debugging instead of Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to your question, NetBeans personally recommends that you use Chrome with their extension for HTML5 projects:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/webclient/html5-gettingstarted.html

Hope that works for you!

Comment: I don't think that will help me because to run a cordova application inside a browser I need something like Ripple Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

2 things that might help: Make sure you have Cordova plugin called "Debugger Console" in your project

Second thing try to use NetBeans dev build from [here](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) . The dev build contains importnant fix -  IDs of core Cordova plugins has been changed recently and as a result NetBeans could be removing these plugins from build when building the project.

Comment: I clearly stated that " I have made sure the Debugger Console plugin is selected (inside the project properties)". Also, the url where Netbeans grabs the plugin is correct.

Comment: It is not about the URL, but about the plugin ID https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=251600

Comment: Yes, of course. I checked the ID and the URL inside `plugins.properties` file. The problem wasn't that it wasn't working. The problem was that I was expecting Netbeans to catch the log entries made by `console.log` calls. Maybe it can clear the confusion if you read my answer.

Comment: Well NetBeans should catch these logs :) If it is not working, file a bug against NetBeans (and please provide details steps to reproduce and would be greate to attach sample project) and we will look at it.

Comment: I filed the bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252057 Hopefully it wasn't an user's fault (me). I pretty much followed the instructions straight up.